# Set default value to ValueListBox in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I'm a beginner in GWT. I have a `ValueListBox` which contains a list of quarters. This list is returned from service backend. My issue is to set the actual quarter of the year as a default value. I tried many attempts but I didn't succeed.

```
 private ValueListBox<String> getQuarters() {
    return new ValueListBox<String>(new Renderer<String>() {
        @Override
        public String render(String instance) {
            return instance != null ? instance : "--select one--";
        }

        @Override
        public void render(String instance, Appendable appendable) throws IOException {
            appendable.append(render(instance));
        }
    });
}

 private void populateQuarterList(final ValueListBox<String> quarterYears) {
    TestRpcAsync.INSTANCE.getListOfQuarters(new AsyncCallback<List<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<String> result) {
            quarterYears.setAcceptableValues(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `https://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueListBox.html#setValue-T-`?

Comment: I tried to use `NodeList<Element> options = quarterYears.getElement().getElementsByTagName("option");`  but I get undefined

Comment: Why not simple `quarterYears.setValue(<YourDefualtValue>)'

Comment: @Jens `quarterYears.setValue(<YourDefualtValue>)` solve the problem, thanks